# How to get the url of soup represents?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to get the url of the page after BeautifulSoup?

```
res = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```

How to get `http://www.example.com` from soup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup.url = 'http://www.example.com'
```

After passing `soup` to the function, you can call `soup.url` to get `http://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the url from the requests object as:

```
res = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
res.url
```

`BeautifulSoup` is a markup parser, thus it only knows of the html of the res.text that you pass to it. If the website url is used somewhere in the website, you can, however, use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the appropriate element and get that url.

It is far from the best approach though.

Comment: Thank you, Simas. However, I pass `soup` to a function and want to get the url from it instead of `res.url`.

Comment: as i mentioned, in that case, the url has to be present in the markup `res.txt` that you pass to the soup constructor. In your case, you might want to try a roundabout approach and modify the res.text response, adding the website url to the markup (i.e. ''.join([res.text, '<siteUrl>www.site-url.com</siteUrl>']), before you pass it to the soup. Then you can retrieve the url by asking soup to look up the siteUrl selector

Answer (score 0):

If webpage has a `link` tag you can get the url with using

```
link = soup.find('link')
print (link['href'])
```

else you can't get the url with using BeautifulSoup(if its not in any html tags).In this case use `res.url` like @Simas said above or use request.Request(actually its the same with `res.url` but usage is different) like :

```
import requests
req = requests.Request('GET', 'http://www.example.com')
url = req.url
print (url)
```